Trying to create a filter based on year in a faceted search in Apex Oracle and it doesn't work
I'm trying to create a filter for my faceted search based on the release year of a movie in my database.
Created a new facet, made it a checkbox group, the source data it's based on is in the correct format (MM/DD/YYYY) and for the list of values I set it for SQL Query and gave it this
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RELEASE_DATE) AS year_display
                , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RELEASE_DATE) AS year
FROM MOVIE3
ORDER BY year_display;

The problem is that when I would load the app itself I could see the years right there for a split second before they'd disappear.

Is there any server side condition which causes that?

I don't think so? Like the query does find stuff for the filter area it's just that it immediately disappears when I open the app

Did you include the "Year" as it's own column ? I created a facet search on the following query (on sample emp table) and it created a facet on year:
select TO_CHAR(extract(YEAR FROM hiredate)) as year , ename, job from emp

result:


I don't have year as its own column but as part of a "release_date" one (ex: 01/27/2024). I tried doing it like this
select DISTINCT TO_CHAR(extract(YEAR FROM RELEASE_DATE)) as year ,TO_CHAR(extract(YEAR FROM RELEASE_DATE)) as ReleaseYear from MOVIE3;
and in SQL Commands it does give me the proper years but when I try to put it a new Facet it just doesn't find anything.

Put it in it’s own column as i’ve shown

The value in the facet needs to correspond to a column in the report. If your facet has a year value and your query has a date - it cannot map that. The facet disappears because no values in the facet map to a value in the column.

ohhhhhhh got it got it. Sorry i'm dumb  Thanks a lot!
